# two column divs in bootstrap3 modal

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I tried to place two divs side by side in an BS3 modal body.

I set the left and right div with width 70%,30% respectively.

But the right div moved to the next line.

So I decrease the left div width to 69%, and it worked.http://jsfiddle.net/t2NcN/5/

Could some one tell me why the 70% failed?http://jsfiddle.net/t2NcN/6/
Many thanks.

```
 .modal-dialog{
    width:90%;

  }
 #wrap{
   padding:0;
   margin:0;
   width:100%;
 }
 #left_div{
    width:70%;
    display:inline-block;
}
#right_div{
    width:30%;
    display:inline-block;    
}
```

Comment: Why not use the BS grid system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the spaces between the closing tag of the first div and the opening tag of the second:

`</div><div id="right_div">`

and it will work. The line break probably breaks the CSS rules and adds a small gap between the two divs which causes the right div to get down.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t2NcN/7/)

Answer (score 0):

If you're ok with 66.66% and 33.33% (as opposed to 70/30), you could just use `class="col-xs-8"` and `col-xs-4`. This solves the problem and avoids custom css altogether.